# I made a onefile executable with pyinstaller, but I can't use the gpu

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I created a deep learning model using tensorflow-gpu and created a onefile with pyinstaller to deploy.
I ran this onefile using cmd, but it was executed with cpu, not gpu.
When I ran it in python, I confirmed that it goes back to the gpu.
In my computer, cuda and cudnn are all installed normally, and I confirmed that they are working normally.
Can you tell me why the gpu doesn't work when I run it in cmd?

Comment: Could you please check the [build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) and [steps](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) to install the TensorFlow are correct by checking the given link. Also please make sure you are not installing `TensorFlow > 2.10` to have GPU support in Windows OS as `TensorFlow 2.10` was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPUs on native-Windows.